# Why is not a single grounder deformed in The 100?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-100

Due to the radiation, at least some of them should have been deformed. The people in the desert produced deformed offspring, and the deformed were outcast, or killed.

But all grounders are very strongly built. Why is that so?

Comment: For all we know, the non-deformed desert people might be as strong/healthy as the grounders, right?

Comment: Yes! and they have more survival capabilities..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Woods Clan](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/The_Woods_Clan) are so selective that

> If a child is born with a mutation, they are cast out and abandoned to
>   erase the stain from the bloodline
>   <sub>-[The 100 Wikia: "The Woods Clan"](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/The_Woods_Clan)</sub>

This is the reason they have no single deformed member.

As for *"All grounders are very strongly built"*, that's because:

> Most children begin to learn from a young age how to be warriors, and
>   are taught English, weapon skills, and their people's customs.
>   <sub>-[The 100 Wikia: "The Woods Clan"](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/The_Woods_Clan)</sub>

Note that **the woods clan** are also called **trikru** in their own language, which is *[Trigedasleng](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/Trigedasleng)*.

Answer (score 2):

This is all speculation, but I believe that the grounders had an immediate tolerance to the radiation after all the bombs detonated. I think that was the writers way of creating new different cultures on the ground. For example:

- mountain men have zero tolerance and will die if exposed
- desert people developed a tolerance, but not before being deformed from exposure
- grounders had a tolerance for the radiation from the beginning
- sky people developed some sort of tolerance in space before returning to earth

I think it's just there way of utilizing Darwinism to create the different cultures in the show.

Comment: After writing this answer I just realized that all the grounders seem to be of Native American/Hispanic/black/Pacific Islander descent, while the mountain men all seem to be of white descent, and the desert people of Indian/Arabian descent. Or something to that effect.

Comment: Is that racism in effect? Just saying ... Nevermind

Comment: It could be that there *are* deformed grounders, right? Maybe they get killed by the community, maybe they don’t become warriors, maybe they live in special villages, …

Comment: Yeah, that could very well be true.

Answer (score 1):

They do exist.

They're called [Nomadic Grounders](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/Grounders#Nomadic_Grounders), Wastelanders or Frikdreina (derogatory term). Normally, they get cast out and left to die.

> Nomadic Grounders, also known as Wastelanders or Frikdreina, are Grounders who have no clan because they or a family member may have been **seen as a "stain on the bloodline" due to birth defects and cast out**. So far, they seem to inhabit the Dead Zone with some of them on their way to the City of Light in search of safe haven.

The most memorable one of them is [Emori](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/Emori) who first appeared in the 2nd season and still part of the main/recurring cast.

You can see some of the others in the link above.

[image]

And to clarify, They're grounders, or at least were born as grounders but got cast out and now (usually) live in the desert.